# How to change newsletter email?

Tags: support, newsletter

I've changed the "Q&A Emails" settings to email I use. How do I change "Newsletter" email setting?

Comment: You can't change it, the only way is explained in the dupe, and it's to subscribe using Incognito browser mode, then you can provide a custom email address.