# Newsletter email address cannot be changed

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, email, newsletter

Is there a reason that it is not possible to change the mail address used for newsletters?

According to a comment in [How to change newsletter email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286916) the only way to change it is to unsubscribe all newsletters and create them outside the account while being logged out.

It is possible to change the mail address used for sending me notifications and even questions with tags I subscribed to via `Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences -> Q&A Emails`.

Would it be possible to add a similar text field to the `Newsletter` block below? Or maybe just use the same address for both?